# I Can't open port 30120 - Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I want to host a FiveM server on my VPS, but I'm unable to open a port for this (30120). I've already added a rule to UFW and iptables, but I can't still pass the *nmap* test. Here is what i got:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-06 14:53 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up.
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
30120/tcp filtered unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.04 seconds
root@VPS:~# nmap -sV 30120 localhost

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-06 14:53 CEST
setup_target: failed to determine route to 30120 (0.0.117.168)
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000040s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
21/tcp   open  ftp     vsftpd 3.0.3
22/tcp   open  ssh     OpenSSH 7.2p2 Ubuntu 4ubuntu2.2 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
53/tcp   open  domain  ISC BIND 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu
80/tcp   open  http    Apache httpd 2.4.18 ((Ubuntu))
3306/tcp open  mysql   MySQL 5.5.5-10.0.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
Service Info: OSs: Unix, Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 9.07 seconds
```

As you can see port 30120 is filtered and the reason for this is that it can't determine route (I'm not sure what does it mean). UFW and netstat -aunt says that I'm already lisening on this port

```
root@VPS:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
9987                       ALLOW       Anywhere
10011                      ALLOW       Anywhere
30033                      ALLOW       Anywhere
25565                      ALLOW       Anywhere
20                         ALLOW       Anywhere
21                         ALLOW       Anywhere
30110                      ALLOW       Anywhere
30120                      ALLOW       Anywhere
3306                       DENY        Anywhere
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9987 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
10011 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30033 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25565 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
20 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30110 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30120 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306 (v6)                  DENY        Anywhere (v6)
```

And here is the netstat output (xxx.xx.xx.xx - IP adress of my VPS):

```
root@VPS:~# netstat -aunt
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30120           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30033           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xx.xx:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10011           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xx.xx:22         37.47.130.222:4372      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xx.xx:22         54.197.3.109:37996      SYN_RECV
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xx.xx:22         218.65.30.25:29523      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    448 xxx.xx.xx.xx:22         37.47.130.222:16716     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xx.xx:22         221.194.47.224:53806    TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xx.xx:22         221.194.47.224:56732    TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::30033                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::10011                :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 xxx.xx.xx.xx:36538      194.97.114.3:2010       ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9987            0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 xxx.xx.xx.xx:2011       194.97.114.3:2010       ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 xxx.xx.xx.xx:53         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 :::9987                 :::*
udp6       0      0 0.0.0.0:30120           :::*
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*
```

I also have this port opened in *iptables*

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http /* 'dapp_Apache' */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https /* 'dapp_Apache%20Full' */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9987
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:9987
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10011
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:10011
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:30033
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:30033
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:25565
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:25565
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp-data
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:20
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:fsp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:30110
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:30110
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:30120
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:30120
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:mysql
```

Does someone have any idea why this port is still closed?

Comment: This port is being listened by some service using UDPv6 protocol. Technically it is open. Do you know which service is using it? Its configuration file?

Comment: FiveM server is ls listening on this port, but i'm still unable to connect via this port. @edit I can change port that I'm listening on, for example to 25565 - which works perfect with minecraft server, but doesn't work for FiveM.

Comment: Does FiveM server config file contain any lines about which protocol to use?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/R2CGfsQV As you can see, there is only info about which port to use.

Comment: Try to change in line **endpoint_add_tcp "0.0.0.0:30120"** 0.0.0.0 to your IP-address.

Comment: It still doesn't work. All it does is that now i can see my IP in netstat instead of 0.0.0.0